# execution of function only once

Tags: c++, opengl

I am playing with ability to synchronize displaying of two different textures on a quad whed row (position) of music changes. The music is in tracker format. It consists of patterns that contains rows. The tracker's API returns the currently playing line (row). I need to display only once first texture on the quad and next only once second texture when row (position) changes. In `DrawGLScene()`, the `drawNoise()` function is called always in each iteration. One line of music takes 0.09 seconds. The `intPosCurrVal` variable has the same value for these 0.09 seconds. Therefore, the function `drawNoise()` is called many times for a period of 0.09 seconds for the same value of `intPosCurrVal`. The `intPosCurrVal` variable increments when the next line of music is played. I would like to call `drawNoise()` only once for the same value of the `intPosCurrVal` variable. In other words, in the main drawing function, which is called all the time, I would like to call only once the function `drawNoise()` as the value of the `intPosCurrVal` variable increases by 1.

Main drawing function:

```
int DrawGLScene(GLvoid)                     
{
    int posCurrVal = Music_GetPosition();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    drawNoise(intPosCurrVal);
    // some other code

    glFlush();
    return TRUE;    
}
```

`drawNoise` function:

```
void drawNoise( int x )
{  
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

    if( x > prev )
    {
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texPosNoise );
        prev = x;
    }
    else
    {
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texNegNoise );
    }

    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glColor3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
    glTexCoord2f( 0.0, 0.0 ); glVertex3f( - 15.0, - 15.0, 0.0 );
    glTexCoord2f( 0.0, 1.0 ); glVertex3f( - 15.0, 15.0, 0.0 );
    glTexCoord2f( 1.0, 1.0 ); glVertex3f( 15.0, 15.0, 0.0 );
    glTexCoord2f( 1.0, 0.0 ); glVertex3f( 15.0, - 15.0, 0.0 );
    glEnd();

    glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Save `posCurrVal`, only call `drawNoise` when the saved value differs from `posCurrVal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me there are many possible solutions to this. One might be to have `DrawGLScene` return the value of `posCurrVal`. That is, it will return the position that it sent to `DrawNoise`, and you can save it somewhere. Then, when it is time to call `DrawGLScene` again, you send it the value you saved earlier (as a new argument you need to add to the function definition). Now you can compare that value to the value you get from `Music_GetPosition()`, and only call `DrawNoise` if the value has changed.

This is just one possible solution -- I'm sure you can come up with others that might be more appropriate to your code.